# Formula for Laplace transform of the jump probability in a continuous time random walk

Tags: probability, expected-value, laplace-transform, random-walk

I am trying to understand the basics of continuous time random walks, and this formula has no explanation as far as I can find:

$$\hat{p}_{n}(s) = \hat{\rho}(s)^n\cdot\frac{1-\hat{\rho}(s)}{s}$$

Where $p_{\hphantom{.}n}(t)$ is the probability of $n$ jumps in $t$ time (meaning that the $n$th jump has occured before time $t$ and the $n+1$-th will occur after time $t$), $\rho(t)$ is the PDF of the wait time distribution between jumps, and the hat above them denotes each one's respective Laplace transform.

I have seen an article that managed to develop $\hat{p}_{n}(s)$ into

$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[e^{-s t_n}\cdot\frac{1-e^{-s\tau_{n+1}}}{s}\bigg]$$

Where $t_n$ is the time of the $n$th jump and $\tau_{n+1}$ is $t_{n+1} - t_n$. But then it immediately said that's equal to the aforementioned formula with no explanation, and I couldn't find anything that could explain the equality earlier in the article, nor any citations.

If it's of any help, I also found another article that wrote it was "because of the convolution property of Laplace transforms".

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: out of curiosity would you be able to share the source of the first equation you're referring to in your post?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this qualifies as an answer since I'm self-taught when it comes to Laplace transforms - but I think I've come across something similar whilst trying to handle the following adjacent problem:

Consider a Poisson-distributed variable $B(t)$ denoting a random event, so that the probability of $n$ event arrivals in any interval of length $t$ is $\mathrm{Pr}\left[B(t)=n \right]=\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}, \ n=0,1,2,\dots$. Taking the Laplace transform of this expression you get the following:
$$ \begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{ \mathrm{Pr}\left[B(t)= n \right] \right\} &= \mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda t}  \right\}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}  e^{st}\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}e^{-\lambda t}}{n!} dt \\
&=\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n}e^{-t(s+\lambda)}dt \\
&=\frac{(\lambda t)^{n}}{n!}\left[ \frac{n!}{(\lambda+s)^n} \frac{1}{(\lambda+s)} \right] \\
&=\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+s} \right)^{n+1}\frac{1}{\lambda} \\
&=\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+s} \right)^{n}\frac{1}{\lambda+s}
\end{align}
$$

Now, you might already know that the Poisson and negative exponential are related [Wagner (1975)](https://archive.org/details/principlesofoper00wagn) p.860. So much so that the previous expression can be written in terms of the transform of the negative exponential density function - what you call $\rho(t)$ in your query i.e. $\rho(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$. This becomes evident once you take the Laplace transform of the negative exponential density function:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{ \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \right\} &= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}dt \\
&= \lambda \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t(s+\lambda)} \\
&= \lambda \left[ \frac{1}{s+\lambda}  \right] \\
&= \frac{\lambda}{s + \lambda} \\
&= \widehat{\rho}(s)
\end{align}
$$

Also notice that, based on the above: $ 1-\mathcal{L}\left\{ \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \right\} = \frac{s}{\lambda  + s} $

This means that we can rewrite the initial expression in such a way that it yields the right-hand side of the equation you're inquiring about i.e.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{ \mathrm{Pr}\left[B(t) = n \right] \right\} &= \mathcal{L}\left\{ \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \right\}^{n} \frac{1}{s}\left( 1  - \mathcal{L}\left\{ \lambda e^{-\lambda t} \right\} \right) \\
&= \widehat{\rho}(s)^n \frac{1}{s}\left( 1  - \widehat{\rho}(s) \right)
\end{align}
$$

Finally, regarding your point on the convolution properties of the Laplace transform: [Muth (1977)](https://archive.org/details/transformmethods0000muth) p.196-197 shows that the density function of the sum of two independent random variables  equals the convolution of the density functions of the two respective random variables.

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables with probability density function $f_{X}(t)$ and $f_{Y}(t)$, respectively, then their sum $Z = X + Y$ has probability density function $f_{Z}(t)$ whose Laplace transform is $\mathcal{L}\left\{ f_{Z}(t)\right\}=E\left[ e^{-s(X+Y)}\right]=E\left[  e^{-sX}\right]E\left[e^{-sY}\right]= \mathcal{L}\left\{ f_X(t) \right\} \mathcal{L}\left\{ f_Y(t) \right\}=\tilde{f}_{X}\tilde{f}_{Y}$. Therefore $ f_{X+Y}(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{ \tilde{f}_{X}(s)\tilde{f}_{Y}(s) \right\}= f_X(t) \ast f_Y(t)$. This result builds on the fact that the expected value of a function of a random variable X is $E[g(X)]=\int_{0}^{\infty}g(t)f_X(t)dt$, and that for $g(X)=e^{-sX}$ we can write $E[e^{-sX}]=\mathcal{L}\left\{f_X(t) \right\}$.

In the specific case in which $X$ and $Y$ follow the negative exponential densifty function i.e. $f_X(t)=f_Y(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$, you have that the Laplace transform of their sum $Z = X + Y$ is as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{f_Z(t) \right\} &= E\left[  e^{-sX}\right]E\left[e^{-sY}\right] \\
&=\left( \frac{\lambda}{s + \lambda} \right)^2
\end{align}
$$
which is just $\widehat{\rho}(s)^n$ when $\rho(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ and $n=2$

I hope the above is somewhat useful

Answer (score 0):

Let us adopt good notations. Denote $S_n=\tau_1+\cdots+\tau_n$ where the $\tau_n$ are independent with density $\rho.$ Denote by $\rho_n$ the density of $S_n.$ Therefore
$$p_n(t)=\Pr(S_n<t<S_{n+1})=\int_{0}^t\rho_n(x)dx\int_{t-x}^{\infty}\rho(y)dy.$$ As a consequence
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}p_n(t)dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\left[\int_{0}^t\rho_n(x)dx\int_{t-x}^{\infty}\rho(y)dy\right]dt=$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\rho_n(x)\left[\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-s(t-x)}\left(\int_{t-x}^{\infty}\rho(y)dy\right)dt\right]dx=$$$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\rho_n(x)dx\times \left[\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sr}\left(\int_{r}^{\infty}\rho(y)dy\right)dr\right]=$$$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\rho_n(x)dx\times \left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho(y)\left(\int_{0}^{y}e^{-sr}dr\right)dy\right]=$$$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sx}\rho_n(x)dx\times \left[\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho(y)\left(\frac{1-e^{-sy}}{s}\right)dy\right]=\hat{\rho}(s)^n\frac{1-\hat{\rho}(s)}{s}.$$ In other terms, $p_n(t)$ is the density of $S_n+U\tau_{n+1}$ where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and is independent of $S_n$ and $\tau_{n+1}.$